# SoapClient: The extern component has failed in processing your requests

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, soap-client

I have created a wcf web service with soap header for client. It is running on cloud.

Now, my issue is that, when I create a reference of that web service in another application/ run through wcf test client, It works properly. But... When I am trying to run this web service through http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html and invoking, It shows me below error:

We are sorry, the requested operation failed. The server returned the following messages

Error Message: SoapClient::SendRequest - No data returned from the remote host:https://abc.cloudapp.net/MyService.svc/MyWebRole.service The extern component has failed in processing your requests.

I have searched a lot for solution. Somebody want to suggest any way to resolve it is highly welcome.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution really, but try to test your service locally - [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) would be my first choice here. Even if your service returns error it will be much easier to debug it than over a remote client you have no control over.

Regards,
Michal